# "There are no OCR keys; creating a new key encrypted with given password" Crashes when running Chainlink node

Tags: chainlink

I am setting up a chainlink node in AWS ec2 + AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) and have followed every step in the documentation (https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/).

Everything runs smoothly until the OCR keys creation step. Once it gets here, it shows *"There are no OCR keys; creating a new key encrypted with given password"*. This is supposed to happen but **the docker container exits right after** (see image below).

[Output after OCR keys creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oONjU.jpg)

I have tried the following:

- Checking whether there is a problem with the specific table these keys are stored in the PostgreSQL database: `public.encrypted_ocr_key_bundles`, which gets populated if this step succeeds. Nothing here so far.
- Using a different version of the Chainlink docker image (see [Chainlink Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/smartcontract/chainlink/tags)). I am currently using version **0.10.0**. No success either, even if using latest ones.
- Using AWS Cloudformation to "let AWS + Chainlink" take care of this, but even so I have encountered similar problems, so no success.

I have thought about populating the OCR table manually with a query, but I am far from having proper OCR key generation knowledge/script in hand so I do not like this option.

Does anybody know what else to try/where the problem could be?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is in your .env file? What's the command you're using to run the node?

Comment: See below my .env file (removed the values for privacy but those are the variables I define):  `ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=4
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_ESTIMATOR_MODE=BlockHistory
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
ETH_URL=
DATABASE_URL=` And the command to run the node: `cd ~/.chainlink-rinkeby && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.15 local n -p /chainlink/.password -a /chainlink/.api`

Comment: @PatrickCollins See my answer in the above comment. Could it be a problem with the ETH client defined in `ETH_URL`? I'm using Infura. Also, `/chainlink/.password` and `/chainlink/.api` are correctly defined based on chainlink password requirements. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably not... but I've not had great success with infura. quite odd... maybe create a new database and try that?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Finally figured it out - it was a memory problem (see update above). Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Can you please add this as the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** It was a simple memory problem. The AWS micro instance (1GB RAM) was running out of memory when OCR keys were generated. I only got a log of the error after switching to an updated version of the CL docker image. In conclusion: migrate to a bigger instance. Should've thought of that but learning never stops!